# .NET Core Test: Moq and In Memory Database cause error primary key duplicate even with different database name

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

So. I hope this is not dumb question. I just dive in into Moq and In Memory Database to Unit testing in ASP.NET C#.

Long story short, I have a simple unit test using repository pattern and in memory database in same unit test class. The problem is, even without adding data, it cause duplicate primary key, which it shouldn't be. But if I use only one of it, it won't cause any error, either in memory database or Moq.

I also tried to change the db name, but the error still the same. I already look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/69194380/4906348. And other question in SA.

The question is, does Moq and in memory db can't work together in same unit test?

This is the code

```cs
using Moq;
using MvcNet;
using MvcNet.Controllers;
using Post.Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Post.Infrastructure;

namespace Post.UnitTests;

public class ListBlog_UnitTest
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<PostContext> _dbOptions;
    private readonly PostContext postContext;
    public ListBlog_UnitTest()
    {
        _dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PostContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "in-memory")
            .Options;
        this.postContext = new PostContext(_dbOptions);
        postContext.posts.AddRange(GetPosts());

        // postContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    private List<Post.Domain.Models.PostModel> GetPosts()
    {
        return new List<Domain.Models.PostModel>() {
            new Domain.Models.PostModel()
            {
                id = 1,
                comments = new List<Post.Domain.Models.PostCommentModel>(),
                title = "title 1",
                content = "ASD ASD ASD",
            },
            new Domain.Models.PostModel()
            {
                id = 2,
                comments = new List<Post.Domain.Models.PostCommentModel>(),
                title = "title 2",
                content = "ASD ASD ASD",
            },
        };
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ListBlog_ReturnList()
    {
        var fakePostRepo = new Mock<IPostRepository>();
        fakePostRepo
            .Setup(pr => pr.GetPostsAsync())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(GetPosts()));
 

        var fakeCommentRepo = new Mock<IPostCommentRepository>();
 
        fakeCommentRepo.Setup(cr => cr.AddComment(new Domain.Models.PostCommentModel()
        {
            id = 1,
            postId = 1,
            name = "a",
            email = "abc@abc.com",
            content = "aaa",
            insertDate = DateTime.Now,
            publishDate = DateTime.Now
        }));
        
 

        var homeCtrl = new HomeController(postRepository: fakePostRepo.Object, commentRepository: fakeCommentRepo.Object);

        var res = homeCtrl.Blog(0);
        var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(res);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<List<Post.Domain.Models.PostModel>>(viewResult.ViewData.Model);
        var list = (List<Post.Domain.Models.PostModel>)viewResult.ViewData.Model;
        Assert.True(list.Count > 0);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestRepoAdd()
    {
        // Given
        var postRepo = new Post.Infrastructure.PostRepository(this.postContext);
        // When
        var data = postRepo.GetPostsAsync().Result;
        
        postRepo.AddPost(new Domain.Models.PostModel()
        {
            id = 5,
            comments = new List<Post.Domain.Models.PostCommentModel>(),
            title = "title 3",
            content = "ASD ASD ASD",
        });
        postRepo.SaveChange();
        var data2 = postRepo.GetPostsAsync().Result;

        // Then 
        Assert.True(data.Count < data2.Count);
    }
}
```

The rest of the code are available in https://github.com/benyaminl/dotnet-core-mvc/tree/multi-project/Post.UnitTests

Any explanation is apreciated. I also try to deep dive into the .NET arch for Containerized app, but seems it's not there, or I'm not thorough enough.

Thank you